# PHP forum site web crawler Runs only once, printing only one <tr> of table

Tags: php

I have this web crawler script with which i m trying to get data from forum sites. 
I have tried many sites so far, and all did worked fine, while except one site, where the code outputs only one link from a  of the whole table (leaving rest of the  untouched.

the forum site HTML site as goes:

```
<table summary="forum topics">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="first even topic-3162  row-read">
        <td class="status firstcol"></td>
        <td class="feeds">
          <a href="/feed/get/type/rss/source/lead/id/3162" title="RSS feed" rel="nofollow" class="rss"><span>RSS</span></a>
          <a href="/subscriptions/add/leadid/3162/backto/1" title="subscribe by email" class="email"><span>Email</span></a>
        </td>
        <td class="topic-titles">
          <img src="http://www.ezboard.com/images/posticons/pi_sunglasses.gif" alt="posticon" class="posticon">
          <a href="/topic/3162/step1-prep-diary-mommy-style" title="warning: long post and actually">step1 prep diary - mommy style</a>
        </td>
        <td class="replies">4</td>
        <td class="kudos">0</td>                                                
        <td class="latest lastcol">
          <p class="user-name">
            <a href="/profile/mini/override_id/9695204" title="User Info" class="grayout">
             <img src="http://static.yuku.com/common/bypass/images/user_info_icon.gif" title="View user info." alt="User Info"></a> -->
            <a href="http://mommyduck.pinoyimgforum.yuku.com" title="mommyduck's Profile">mommyduck</a>
          </p>
          <p class="date">Jul 14 13 12:49 AM</p>
        </td>
        <td class="author lastcol">
          <p class="user-name">
           <a href="/profile/mini/override_id/9695204" title="User Info" class="grayout">
            <img src="http://static.yuku.com/common/bypass/images/user_info_icon.gif" title="View user info." alt="User Info"></a> -->
           <a href="http://mommyduck.pinoyimgforum.yuku.com" title="mommyduck's Profile">mommyduck</a></p>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="first odd topic-425  row-hot row-read">
        <td class="status firstcol">
         <img src="http://static.yuku.com/domainskins/bypass/img/ezboard/hottopic.gif" class="icon icon-hot-read" title="This is a hot topic with no new posts" alt="Hot Topic w/ No New Posts">
        </td>
        <td class="feeds">
         <a href="/feed/get/type/rss/source/lead/id/425" title="RSS feed" rel="nofollow" class="rss">
          <span>RSS</span>
         </a>
         <a href="/subscriptions/add/leadid/425/backto/1" title="subscribe by email" class="email"><span>Email</span></a>
        </td>
        <td class="topic-titles">
         <a href="/topic/425/tips-by-a-97er" title="I took my Step1 exam</a>
         <span class="topic-pager">stuff</span>
        </td>
        <td class="replies">46</td>
        <td class="kudos">0</td>                                                
        <td class="latest lastcol">
          <p class="user-name">
            <a href="/profile/mini/override_id/9695204" title="User Info" class="grayout">
             <img src="http://static.yuku.com/common/bypass/images/user_info_icon.gif" title="View user info." alt="User Info">
            </a>
            <a href="http://mommyduck.pinoyimgforum.yuku.com" title="mommyduck's Profile">mommyduck</a>
          </p>
          <p class="date">Jul 11 13  1:16 AM</p>
        </td>
        <td class="author lastcol">
          <p class="user-name">
           <a href="/profile/mini/override_id/2996016" title="User Info" class="grayout">
            <img src="http://static.yuku.com/common/bypass/images/user_info_icon.gif" title="View user info." alt="User Info">
           </a>
           <a href="http://roxter.e.yuku.com" title="roxter's Profile">roxter</a>
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My PHP page code goes as::

```
<?php
    function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
    }
    $returned_content = get_data('http://example.com');
    $first_step = explode( '<table summary="forum topics"' , $returned_content );
    $second_step = explode('</table>', $first_step[1]);

    $third_step = explode('<tr>', $second_step[0]);
    //print_r($third_step);
    foreach ($third_step as $key=>$element) {
    $child_first = explode( '<td class="topic-titles"' , $element );
    $child_second = explode( '</td>' , $child_first[1] );
    $child_third = explode( '<a href=' , $child_second[0] );
    $child_fourth = explode( '</a>' , $child_third[1] );
    $final = "<a href=".$child_fourth[0]."</a></br>";
    ?>
    <li target="_blank" class="itemtitle">
        <span class="item_new"></span><?php echo $final?>
    </li>
    <?php       
        }
    ?>      
    </ul>        
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

if run this code, it outputs only one link from one  of above HTML, ignoring the other .

NOTE:: the above code is only able to print out  from  with class="topic-titles".

Any Suggestions are appreciated...

Comment: what do you mean..

Comment: but the same code worked for two other sites... and if i have to edit that anchor line, what am i missing?

Comment: @harishk use a html library like simple_html_dom or php native dom. Do not use regex or some php function for scraping website.

Comment: yes, i have code using DOM too. i just wanna see how it looks like with this way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `explode('<tr>'...`.

However there is only one element inside the fetched `table` that has a `tr` with no class (ie. "`<tr>`").

If you absolutely must scrape using this string splitting method, you'll want your explode to be based upon `"<tr"` not `"<tr>"`

A quick jQuery query on the [website you're trying to scrape](http://pinoyimgforum.yuku.com/forums/1/Step-1/Step-1) confirms this

[image]

Comment: hey man, it works fine now.. but i actually gives an error along with the result as `unidentified offset 1` with anchor link to it as `</a`    .. do you know why i m seeing this..?

Comment: it's likely that because you're just `echo`ing out the scraped html, and you're `explode`ing on partial html tags, that you're creating all manner of half formed html tags as a result. you should try wrapping all your scrapped data in the PHP `htmlspecialchars` function and looking at just what you're spitting out. Similarly you may find that `$child_first[1]` and `$child_third[1]` are trying to refer to array elements that dont exist, again, you should look at what you're scraping to identify this